# jquery: how to find a single character in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm looking for a way to detect wheter my label object has a "-" character in it.

```
<label>blabla</label>  -> has not
<label>bla-bla</label> -> has
```

Im not to familiar with regular expressions.

Comment: If you are trying to find the labels that contain a "-" then you can use the inbuilt contains selector.
i.e:

    var labels = $("label:contains(-)");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First get the contents of the label, then use the regex `/-/`.

```
> "blabla".match(/-/)
> null

> "bla-bla".match(/-/)
> ["-"]
```

You don't even need a regex here, you can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
> "blabla".indexOf('-')
> -1

> "bla-bla".indexOf('-')
> 3
```

If you just want to select the `label` element if it contains a "-", you could use:

```
$('label:contains("-")')
```

It depends on what you are trying to do.